# pandas сортировка по времени с заданным интервалом и суммирование

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Необходимо отсортировать столбцы по времени с интервалом в 5 минут без округления и суммировать значения другого столбца.

Csv файл на 600 тысяч строк выглядит примерно вот так:

| Время | Кол-во |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-05 10:00:23 | 2 |
| 2022-07-05 10:01:11 | 5 |
| 2022-07-05 10:01:16 | 1 |
| 2022-07-05 10:01:33 | 2 |
| 2022-07-05 10:04:26 | 15 |
| 2022-07-05 10:05:57 | 1 |
| 2022-07-05 10:05:57 | 1 |
| 2022-07-05 10:05:57 | 3 |

И так вплоть до 23:59:59

Я пробую что-то вроде:

```py
def V_t_5_Min():
    df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(Ex_Csv,  usecols = ["Время", 'Кол-во']))
    a = df['Время'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Время'])
    b = df['Кол-во']
    c = pd.Series(a).dt.round("5T", 0)
    df = pd.DataFrame(c)
    df['Кол-во'] = b
    c = df.groupby('Время')
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(c.sum())
    df1.to_csv('Datasets\CSV\V_5_min.csv')
    print('Датасет Объём/5-Минут готов')
    print(' ')
```

Но получаю ужасное округление и неверные расчёты Кол-во

Желаемый результат для интервала в 5 минут

| Время | Кол-во |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-05 10:05:00 | 30 |

и так далее для каждой 5 минуты

Comment: вы не про rolling() ?

Comment: Я может что то не правильно понял, но по документаций попробовал
      
def V_t_5_Min():
    df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(Ex_Csv,  usecols = ["Время", 'Кол-во']))
    a = df['Время'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Время'])
    b = a.rolling('2S')
    print(b)
                   
Выдало ошибку window must be an integer 0 or greater

Comment: что вообще означает "отсортировать по времени с интервалом"?

Comment: Из csv файла где может быть 50 строк с одним и тем же временем но разным кол-вом отсортировать все значения начиная с 10:00:00 по 5 минут при этом сложить Кол-во в эти 5 минут

Comment: Нужно округлить время по 5 минут в отдельную переменную, а потом сгруппировать по ней датафрейм, ну и сумму потом сделать. С виду вы что-то похожее и делаете, только зачем-то много промежуточных каких-то действий непонятно зачем нужных

Comment: похоже здесь может пригодиться `resample`